# Converting 2 list and one string to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
P.S: Thank you everybody ,esp Matthias Fripp . Just reviewed  the question You are right I made mistake : String is value not the key 
num=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
pow=[1,4,9,16,25,36]
s= ":subtraction"    
dic={1:1 ,0:s , 2:4,2:s, 3:9,6:s, 4:16,12:s.......}
```

There is easy way to convert two list to dictionary :

```
newdic=dict(zip(list1,list2))
```

but for this problem no clue even with comprehension:

```
print({num[i]:pow[i] for i in range(len(num))})
```

Comment: Desired output is **not** a dict. Dict cannot have duplicated keys.

Comment: the duplicate keys will go away, do you want to keep them?

Comment: Even in the updated version you may have some duplicated keys, e.g. 2 is used as the key for two different values in your new example.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, this would do what you want:

```
nums = [(n, p) for (n, p) in zip(num, pow)]
diffs = [('subtraction', p-n) for (n, p) in zip(num, pow)]
items = nums + diffs
dic = dict(items)
```

However, a dictionary cannot have multiple items with the same key, so each of your "subtraction" items will be replaced by the next one added to the dictionary, and you'll only get the last one. So you might prefer to work with the `items` list directly.

If you need the `items` list sorted as you've shown, that will take a little more work. Maybe something like this:

```
items = []
for n, p in zip(num, pow):
    items.append((n, p))
    items.append(('subtraction', p-n))
# the next line will drop most 'subtraction' entries, but on 
# Python 3.7+, it will at least preserve the order (not possible 
# with earlier versions of Python)
dic = dict(items)
```

Comment: P.S: Thank you everybody ,esp Matthias Fripp . Just reviewed the question You are right I made mistake : String is value not the key    . Matthias Fripp very smooth solution . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `dict` cannot contain duplicate keys. You can make key duplicate with a little bit of tweaking. I used `OrderedDict` to keep order of inserted keys:

```
from pprint import pprint
from collections import OrderedDict

num=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
pow=[1,4,9,16,25,36]

pprint(OrderedDict(sum([[[a, b], ['substraction ({}-{}):'.format(a, b), a-b]] for a, b in zip(num, pow)], [])))
```

Prints:

```
OrderedDict([(1, 1),
             ('substraction (1-1):', 0),
             (2, 4),
             ('substraction (2-4):', -2),
             (3, 9),
             ('substraction (3-9):', -6),
             (4, 16),
             ('substraction (4-16):', -12),
             (5, 25),
             ('substraction (5-25):', -20),
             (6, 36),
             ('substraction (6-36):', -30)])
```